# Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite help

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am trying to get Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite to get clean urls.
I have links such as

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?view=pageName">Page Name</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?view=pageName2">Page Name2</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?view=pageName3">Page Name3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and url comes out to be

```
http://example.com/user/index.php?view=pageName
```

I would like to clean the url in the address bar it to this

```
http://example.com/user/pageName
```

**Edit: This is what's in my httpd.conf if it's any use.**

```
<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/user">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Using phpinfo() I have verified that mod_rewrite is loaded and I have this in my .htaccess (user file, Not root .htaccess) and not virtual user on apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /user/ #Edited rewrite base added in, but not helping much.
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteRule ^/user/([a-zA-Z])/?$ index.php?view=$1  [NC,L]
```

**Edit: the rest of my .htaccess**

```
#Ensure browser reads Header
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
Header unset Last-Modified

#Set caching expires
Header set Expires On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"

#gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

does not work the same on all menu links which are identical in html structure, and not working properly. IE: It sends me to `http://example.com/user/?view=pageName`, but is loading the root HTML file content.

If I change this line

```
RewriteRule ^/user/([a-zA-Z])/?$ index.php?view=$1  [NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.google.com  [NC,L]
```

I get sent to google as expected. So obviously I must be doing something wrong with the matching and replacing, but what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** 
access.log and error.log are error free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Had to change HTML URL style to be used as such

```
<a href="pageName">Page Name</a>
```

Then in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteBase /user/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also had to disable mod_cache.so from apache's httpd.conf as it interfere with rewrite if there are any caches left behind. Hope this helps others to get clean urls working.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^/user/([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?view=$1  [NC,L]
```

you are missing the + so you are not matching words, just a single char

Comment: @robx sorry i used to check my rule(with +) but while posting i used your rule, that time i forgot "+" ...

Comment: I've tried with the plus as well, doesn't change anything here. no clean urls, but i can use R=301 type and redirect to other domains like google when the base url /user is hit.

Comment: Maybe it's something else causing it, but i have no clue what it could be since i can redirect to other domains. Could it be the way my url is structured in php?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^/user/([a-zA-Z])?$ index.php?view=$1  [NC,L]
```

try this..(one slash removed)

Comment: not working. and weird thing is, i have several ul lists, each ul the last li link would default to http://example.com/index.php?view=pageName while the rest directs me to http://example.com/?view=pageName. That's really bizarre no?

Comment: any other rules before or after this rule in .htaccess?

Comment: yeah, but didn't think it would affect the mod rewrite. I'll edit and post my whole little htaccess.

Comment: i tried it with removing [NC,L] on my server it working here. post your .htaccess to help more.

Comment: I did post edit and posted it. That is my whole .htaccess and I have no root .htaccess file. Removing [NC,L] did nothing on my end. No error, and would allow me to redirect to other sites, but don't actually clean my url.